# Describe an affine transformation $f \circ H_0^\lambda \circ f^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Describe an affine transformation $f \circ H_0^\lambda \circ f^{-1}$, where $H_0^\lambda$ denotes a homothety with the center $O \in \mathbb{A}^2$ and the coefficient $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f: \mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ is some arbitrary affine transformation. Actually quite stuck dealing with this task, could you please give some hints/direction on how should I proceed with the task?

Comment: Notice that $f \circ H_O^{\lambda} \circ f^{-1} (f(O)) = f(O)$ and :. $$\overrightarrow{f \circ H_O^{\lambda} \circ f^{-1}} = \overrightarrow{f} \circ \overrightarrow{H_O^{\lambda}} \circ \overrightarrow{f^{-1}} = \overrightarrow{f} \circ (\lambda id) \circ \overrightarrow{f^{-1}} = \lambda id$$

Comment: thanks for the idea!

Comment: Hope it helps .